# Jquery UI Multiselect widget checkall binded method stops working after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback, multi-select

I'm having some issues when I try to use some methods I binded to my multiselect control.

When the page loads, I bind a method to the widget this way:

```
$('#myMultiselect').bind('multiselectcheckall', 
    function(event, ui){
        alert('All Multiselect items selected!');
    });
);
```

but after a partial postback this stops working. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use this when creating your multiselect ?

```
$("#myMultiselect").multiselect({

   checkAll: function(){
      alert('All Multiselect items selected!');
   }

});
```

**EDIT :**
OK, I've understood that `checkAll` only works when clicking on "check all" button. So you will have to get the number of checked items on every click and compare it with the total amount of items, like this :

```
var size = $(this).find('option').size(); //total items amount
var checked = $(this).multiselect('getChecked').size(); //checked items amount
```

Use it with a `click` event, and don't forget to keep the `checkAll` event because clicking "check all" won't fire `click` event :)

```
$("#myMultiselect").multiselect({
   click: function(){
       var size = $(this).find('option').size(); //total items amount
       var checked = $(this).multiselect('getChecked').size(); //checked items amount
       if (size == checked){
           alert('All Multiselect items (manually) selected!');
       }
   },
   checkAll: function(){
       alert('All Multiselect items selected!');
   }
});
```

Here is a demo : [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/E9G4u/)

Hope I helped you !!

Comment: Yes, it's just the other way to bind a method to the  widget. The behavior is the same..

Comment: `checkAll` only fire when you click on "check all" and not when manually checking every items. I've updated my post to make it work manually ;)